# How are security updates classified into low/med/high?

Tags: updates, security

When an update becomes available for a particular piece of software, if I run

```
aptitude changelog <name>
```

I will see urgency as either low, medium or high.

How is it decided which category a fix falls into? And also, should I treat 'high' to mean 'install asap' and 'medium' to mean, 'install when convenient'?

Is there a best practice to follow on how soon high medium or low fixes should be implemented?

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdatePreparation#Update_the_packaging) page, the urgency field isn't used by Ubuntu (at least the security side of it).